# Understanding compiler choice in resolving function overloading

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, overload-resolution

I am compiling on a platform where int= 32 bits  (gcc arm none eabi, cortex M3,  GCC version 9) with the dialect set to C++17.

I have a overloaded a method with both template versions and plain versions of the same method. The normal overloads are in a private base class but have been exposed through a using clause.

```
class MemoryStream {
  public:
    inline void write(bool value);
    inline void write(uint8_t value);
    inline void write(uint16_t value);
    inline void write(uint32_t value);
    inline void write(int16_t value);
    inline void write(int32_t value);
}
```

and

```
class WriteStream :private MemeoryStream {
  public:
    using MemoryStream::write;

  template<typename T>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type WriteStream::write(T obj){
       MemoryStream::write(obj);
    }
}
```

when I call the method using a numeric literal  i.e.

```
    txStream.write(0U);
```

I get the following error:

```
In instantiation of 'typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<_Tp>::value>::type  WriteStream::write(T) [with T = unsigned int; typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<_Tp>::value>::type = void]':
error: call of overloaded 'write(unsigned int&)' is ambiguous
```

1.) Why are the plain overloaded functions not being selected as they are being imported through the using clause and if I call

```
txStream.write<uint32_t>(0U);
```

or

```
constexpr uint32_t Zero =0;
txStream.write<uint32_t>(Zero);
```

They resolve without error ?

Is *unsigned int* seen a a distinct type from *uint32_t* ?

2.) Why is the compiler converting the numeric literal to a reference ??? as shown by the error message: *'call of overloaded write(unsigned int&) is ambiguous'*

Comment: Yes, `unsigned int` is a different type than `uint32_t` On your platform, they may have the same representation, but they're not the same type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting an ambiguous overload error, is because an `unsigned int` *could* be implicitly converted to any of the overload argument types for `MemoryStream::write`. Since there is no direct overload for `unsigned int`, the compiler does not know which overload to select:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type WriteStream::write(T obj){
    //which overload for MemoryStream::write should be selected here?       
    MemoryStream::write(obj);
}
```

This does not happen if you explicitly state the template parameter `txtStream.write<uint32_t>(0U);`, because the argument `0L` is implicitly converted to `uint32_t`. Since a direct overload for `MemoryStream::write` for `uint32_t` exists, you do not get any ambiguity errors.

As for your second question, within the body of `WriteStream::write`, `obj` is an lvalue reference to an `unsigned int`, even though, from your initial function call: `txtStream.write(0L)` the argument is a numerical literal:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type WriteStream::write(T obj){
   //obj is an lvalue reference within this scope to whatever T is
   //  deduced to be (unsigned int in your example)
   MemoryStream::write(obj);
}
```

Comment: Ah, okay, I understand. I may have misunderstood the first question. Is your second question adequately answered?

Comment: Actually I just lifted simplified example from a much larger code base. The private base class  is required because its a common base implementation which exposes methods that would pollute the write stream interface.

Comment: Actually MemoryStream::write() is exactly what I wanted  Because this->write(obj) is recursive and leads to a stack overflow where as MemoryStream::write forces it to use the base class primitive write methods and in the literal case results in a error because as we have learnt int  != int32_t. That is actually why I posted the question because I got the compiler error after I removed the stack overflow   :-)

Comment: Yes, you're correct about the call to `write`, I missed that. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

An `unsigned int` is a distinct type from the fixed width types (even though one of those fixed with types will have the same size as `unsigned int`), so with your code the compiler doesn't know which overload of `write` should be called.

You'll need to provide overloads for `unsigned int` and `int`.

Consider the problems that could arise if on one system, with a 32 bit int, the `write(uint32_t)` was called, while on another system with 16 bit ints *the exact same code* would call `write(uint16_t)` (or substitute "64" for "16"). Or the corresponding chaos if one system would write a 32 bit number while another system would read a different sized one.

Comment: I did some digging and I see that as of C++11 the fixed width types became actual distinct types where before they were just typedefs that where tailored to each deployment platform.

Comment: @AndrewGoedhart: I can’t find any statement to that effect: the `<cstdint>` types often *are* type aliases for certain fundamental types.  In this case, I imagine it’s just that `unsigned long` is also 32 bits and was selected to be `uint32_t`.

Comment: Distinct fixed size types where a feature of C+11 (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) I remember having to define them manually for my own system in the early 2000's

Comment: @AndrewGoedhart: That doesn’t say they’re distinct types, and they certainly [often aren’t](https://godbolt.org/z/PpumBc).

Comment: @David actually gcc is allowing me to define both write(uint32_t) and write(unsigned int) so it is see them as distinct types and when I do so it removes the compile error. Now the question is this correct according to the standard or just a gcc quirk

Comment: Maybe not, maybe this is a regression in the compiler. The only compiler this code struct A {
int g(unsigned a){return a;}
int g(uint32_t a){return a;}
}; compiles on is the Arm gcc versions 8.3 and 9.0

Comment: @David It turns out that the reason it was allowing me to define both was that gcc arm changed their definition of uint32_t to unsigned long from unsigned int somewhere between 8.2 and 8.3.1 :-0